# Crear condicionasl en SQL SERVER basado en resultado de un QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, condiciones, update

Tengo una condicional en SQL SERVER que si se cumple me ejecute el QUERY que necesito, el problema es que el resultado puede contener varias respuestas ya que la condicion es un SELECT a un campo de una tabla y puede haber mas de una linea que de positivo, como puedo corregir esto para que al cumplirse la condicion se ejecute el QUERY?

```
DECLARE @ACTIVO INT;
SET @ACTIVO = (SELECT AG_Fact_Envio FROM SAFACT WHERE TipoFac = 'F' AND CodOper = 'OP-0001' AND FechaPre IS NOT NULL) ;
IF (@ACTIVO IS NULL)
BEGIN
    UPDATE SAFACT
    SET FechaPre = GETDATE() , AG_Fact_Envio = '1'
    WHERE
        TipoFac = 'F'
        AND CodOper = 'OP-0001'
        AND Monto > 0
        AND AG_Fact_Envio IS NULL
    AND FechaPre IS NOT NULL            
END
ELSE IF(@ACTIVO = '1')
BEGIN
    UPDATE SAFACT
    SET FechaPre = GETDATE()
    WHERE
        TipoFac = 'F'
        AND CodOper = 'OP-0001'
        AND Monto = 0
        AND AG_Fact_Envio = '1'
    AND FORMAT(FechaPre,'yyyy-MM-dd') = FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -2,GETDATE()),'yyyy-MM-dd')
END
```

Comment: pues la verdad...hay alguna necesidad de hacer esto con un condicional?, no bastaría con correr el segundo `UPDATE` primero y el otro `UPDATE` después?

Comment: Necesito la condicional dado que el primer UPDATE se me ejecuta cuando el campo AG_Fact_Envio es NULL y el segundo cuando tiene valor 1.

Comment: sí, pero esas condiciones las tienes también en el `WHERE` de tu `UPDATE`....con lo cual, para qué usar un `IF`?

Answer (score 0):

Tal cuál lo planteas eso requiere de un bucle, porque en cada valor de una variable solo puede entrar un valor. Y los bucles no son un camino muy recomendado en TSQL

Yo veo dos estrategias posibles. La primera sería hacer una estructura temporal, por ejemplo una variable de tabla que identifique el valor de lo que llamas activo para todos los registros necesarios, y luego hacer un join con la tabla.

La segunda que no es muy diferente es.

```
With cte as (
SELECT id -- la clave primaria 
     , fechaPre
     , Fact_Envio
    FROM SAFACT 
                WHERE TipoFac = 'F' 
                    AND CodOper = 'OP-0001' 
                    AND FechaPre IS NOT NULL
                    AND Monto > 0
                    AND (
                        AG_Fact_Envio IS NULL 
                        OR 
                        AG_Fact_Envio ='1')
                    AND FechaPre IS NOT NULL 
                    AND AG_Fact_Envio IS NULL
)
-- Antes de ejecutar el update, identifica las filas por 
-- la clave primaria.
-- Select * from cte;
UPDATE cte 
    SET FechaPre = CASE WHEN AG_Fact_Envio = '1' 
                    AND FORMAT(FechaPre,'yyyy-MM-dd') = FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -2,GETDATE()),'yyyy-MM-dd')
                    THEN GETDATE()
                    WHEN AG_Fact_Envio IS NULL THEN GETDATE()
                    ELSE FechaPre END
      , AG_Fact_Envio = CASE WHEN AG_Fact_Envio IS NULL 
                                THEN '1'
                            ELSE AG_Fact_Envio END
```

Creas una `tabla de expresión común` que identifica las filas, por eso he puesto id aunque no se si dispones de esa columna, y las columnas que quieres realizar el update. También puedes añadir todas las columnas que se filtran o mejor dicho que se utilizan en los case, para ver si los resultados son los esperados.

Luego en la salida de la `cte` descomentas el select y comentas el update.

Evalúa si tienes que retocar alguno de los case, o alguna de las condiciones puestas en ellos.

Si te fijas el filtro de la columna Fact_Envio ya incluye las dos posibilidades de los ifs, por tanto en el case tendrás que jugar con ellos, para solo hacer una `update`

Dado que la cte esta formada por una tabla, no te será necesario, ni relacionarla con `SAFACT`, ya que el motor tendrá claro que funciona sobre ese conjunto de datos.
Pero también podrías relacionarlo con esa tabla o con otras si te fuera necesario. `Update s Set.... From cte join saFact s on cte.id = s.id join otro ..`